# DB2 How to check current number of objects in tablespace

Tags: db2

I've got message in Alert Monitor about number of objects in tablespace.
**The tablespace has almost reached .**

My question is how check how many object are already in tablespace?. 
I have found in DB2 docs that *Max # of table 'objects' in a DMS tablespace: 51000.*

Comment: I've found solution by myself. To others with same problem below correct SQL query:

   **db2 "select tbspace, count(*) from syscat.tables group by tbspace"**

Comment: That's not very precise, because it does not account for other objects (index, LOB) that may be in that tablespace. The precise method would be to run the `INSPECT` command for the tablespace and count the number of unique object IDs in the report, pertaining to that tablespace ID.

Comment: @michalp Your query will not *necessarily* return what you are looking for, there are a number of edge cases.